# How to force hugging UILabel content after orientation changes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, autolayout

I have two views (`UILabels`) on my view controller with next layout:
[image: layout]

I want to recalculate constraints after device orientation is changed, so my ***top label*** should take only one line and ***bottom label*** should move up to keep the same offset from ***top label*** (***top label*** is aligned vertically in container).

[image]

How can I achieve it?

If I try to use `[self.toplabel sizeToFit];` it breaks all my size constraint to set new size and, that's important for me, neglect vertical space between these two labels.

I've tried:

```
[self.longLabel sizeToFit];

[self.botLabel layoutIfNeeded];
[self.botLabel setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[self.botLabel updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
[self.botLabel needsUpdateConstraints];
```

But with no result. Constraint don't want to recalculate themselves.

[image]

Comment: How is your `longLabel` holding its `y` position?

Comment: @footyapps27 vertical aligning. The goal is - to centre both labels on the screen. If top label have few lines, it has to push second label down

Comment: @Ossir have you solved it after all?

Comment: @MaximMikheev not with auto layout, still looking for elegant solution, because auto layout is supposed to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `[label sizeToFit];` after change the Orientation.

You can call is with notification method after every orientation change

Comment: That helped! But I have one little problem, please, check out update for question